# Using SAS to do a multiple imputation for survival analysis

Tags: statistics, sas, survival-analysis, imputation, cox-regression

I am using SAS to do a multiple imputation, and I am having trouble figuring out proc MI. I am looking at a comparison of a control with 126 observations to the cases with 63 observations. The missing data is specifically only in the PercentUsed variable. This is what I have so far. Really appreciate any help.

```
proc mi data=FinalMod nimpute=126 seed=12345 out=imputed;
var days case sleep exercise age PercentUsed  ;  
run;

PROC PHREG data= FinalMod;
MODEL days*case(0) =  sleep exercise age PercentUsed/ RISKLIMITS=BOTH
TYPE3(ALL);
RUN;

proc mianalyze data=imputed;
  modeleffects est=phreg;
run;
```

I am expecting results that look similar to the original proc phreg, but slightly different for the PercentUsed variable

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you getting errors in the log, surprising results?  If surprising results, please describe the results you get, and how they differ from your expectation.  There may be more SAS stat folks to help with this over at communities.sas.com.